# Return dynamic columns by joining results of a stored function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored function called `Fnc_MyFunc(@myDate)`. it takes a `date` parameter and return a table like this:

```
user_id | count_laps
--------+-----------
1       | 85
2       | 37
5       | 55
12      | 48
```

i want to execute this for many dates (date interval).
with my function i whant a result like this: (laps per day for all users)

```
user_id | [2015-10-01] | [2015-10-02] | [2015-10-03] | ....
--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------
1       | 85           | 2            | 66           | ....
2       | 37           | 58           | 85           | ....
5       | 55           | 33           | 75           | ....
12      | 48           | 44           | 55           | ....
```

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic sql?

Comment: the only way is dynamic sql. Read and absorb this comprehensive article carefully. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want:

```
SELECT 
    u.userId,
    d1.count_laps as [2015-10-01]
    d2.count_laps as [2015-10-02],
    d3.count_laps as [2015-10-03]
FROM 
    TableOrQueryWithDistinctUserIds u
    LEFT JOIN Fnc_MyFunc('2015-10-01') d1 ON u.userId = d1.userId
    LEFT JOIN Fnc_MyFunc('2015-10-02') d2 ON u.userId = d2.userId
    LEFT JOIN Fnc_MyFunc('2015-10-03') d3 ON u.userId = d2.userId
```

You can then make it dynamic if necessary.